# Increase font size for bootstrap ui angular timepicker

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

How can I increase font size and width of [Bootstrap UI Angular](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) timepicker control?

Basically I want to increase text size and size of Chevron(up down buttons).

This is the markup I have below.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-3"> <span class="h3">Drop off </span></label>
  <div class="control-label col-sm-3">
  <timepicker  name="txtDroptime" ng-model="myDroptime" ng-change="DroptimeChanged()" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian"></timepicker>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The up and down arrows are generated dynamically and are glyphicons. You can target them inside the time picker using the following code:

```
.ng-valid-time .glyphicon {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.ng-valid-time input, .ng-valid-time button {
  font-size: 26px;
}

.ng-valid-time input {
  padding: 0;
}

.ng-valid-time .form-control {
  height: 50px;
}
```

Change the values to your requirement.

[image]

[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/cOKUooI8sT6FW5GvmcY3?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks works great!! Only thing is if I increase the size to 26px the width of textbox does not expand. I tried to set width:85px still no effect.

Comment: Ok thanks.. if I  use following .ng-valid-time input, .ng-valid-time button {
  font-size: 26px; width:85px;
} The text gets chopped off inside the hours and minutes boxes but the meridian box expands correctly.

Comment: I have added the output after adding the extra two rules of CSS code. Check it.